# Is there any LOOKUP function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables with fields as email,pan,mobile no,folio_NO both the tables are having same fields.One of the table name is direct and the other is negative. I have to compare two tables by field wise like email and email,pan and pan... has to be compared and if email is matching than that email should not come in output.Output should be like  A list of emails, which are not mentioned in the Negative table plus the list of phone numbers which are not in Negative t,list of pan numbers which are not in Negative,table i tried below query but still matched emailid's and pan nos were retrieved. Can anyone help on this

```
Select 
 (Case when Direct.Mobile_D=NL_Mobile_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
 (Case when Direct.PAN_D=NL_PAN_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
 (Case when Direct.FOLIO_D=NL_FOLIO_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
 (Case when Direct.EMAIL_D=NL_EMAIL_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
From
(
  (
   SELECT ltrim(rtrim(upper(Mobile))) AS 
Mobile_D,ltrim(rtrim(upper(PAN))) AS PAN_D,ltrim(rtrim(upper(FOLIO))) AS 
FOLIO_D,ltrim(rtrim(upper(EMAIL_ID))) AS EMAIL_D
FROM DIRECT_Table
)DIRECT---table 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
 SELECT ltrim(rtrim(upper(Mobile))) AS Mobile_D,ltrim(rtrim(upper(PAN))) 
AS PAN_D,ltrim(rtrim(upper(FOLIO))) AS 
FOLIO_D,ltrim(rtrim(upper(EMAIL_ID))) AS EMAIL_D
FROM NEGATIVE_Table---table2
)NL
ON  Direct.Mobile_D=NL_Mobile_N
AND Direct.PAN_D=NL_PAN_N
AND Direct.FOLIO_D=NL_FOLIO_N
AND Direct.EMAIL_D=NL_EMAIL_N
)
GROUP BY 
(Case when Direct.Mobile_D=NL_Mobile_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
(Case when Direct.PAN_D=NL_PAN_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
(Case when Direct.FOLIO_D=NL_FOLIO_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
(Case when Direct.EMAIL_D=NL_EMAIL_N THEN NULL ELSE MOBILE_D END)
```

Comment: No need for that `GROUP BY`, simply do `SELECT DISTINCT`!

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is poorly worded, sorry. Do you have to output any non-matching rows or non-matching values per column? (e.g., if the email matches, but phone number doesn't). I am assuming row-base comparison below.

Depending on the database you are using, you may have access to EXCEPT clause, for example:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-union.html

Sample query:

```
SELECT phone, email FROM D_tab
EXCEPT
SELECT phone, email FROM N_tab
```

This will give you the rows from `D_tab` which do not occur in `N_tab`

Comment: Thanks.Output should be non-matching values as per column not row wise

Comment: So what is it that you want in the output? A list of emails, which are not mentioned in the N_table plus the list of phone numbers which are not in N_table? 

Or rows from D_table, where values ever mentioned in the N_table are replaced with NULL ? 

Or .... ?

Edit your question to make it clear and we'll be much more helpful :)